# Inverse $z$-transform of $\frac{z_{1}^{-1}}{1 - az_{1}^{-1}z_{2}^{-2}}$

Tags: inverse, signal-processing, z-transform

I'd like to know how to calculate the inverse $z$-transform of
$$X(z_{1},z_{2}) = \frac{z_{1}^{-1}}{1 - az_{1}^{-1}z_{2}^{-2}},\quad |z_{1}|\cdot |z_{2}|^{2} > |a|.$$

I`ve tried to make the change $$z_{2}^{2}=t$$ And got $$X(z_{1},t) = \frac{z_{1}^{-1}}{1 - az_{1}^{-1}t^{-1}}, \quad |z_{1}|\cdot |t| > |a|.$$
That brought me to $$x(m,n) = a^{m-1}U(m-1)δ(m-n-1),$$ where I cannot define the second variable n.

Comment: Your result for the second $X$ is correct, so for the first $X$ you get
$$\mathcal Z^{-1}[(z_1, z_2) \mapsto z_2^2 (z_1 z_2^2 - a)^{-1}](m, n) = \\
a^{m - 1} [2 m - n - 2 = 0 \land m \geq 0 \land n \geq 0].$$

Comment: Yeah thanks I got $$x(m,n) = a^{m-1}U(m-1)δ(2m-n-2)$$ but I want the clear explanation (why degrees at z are shown this way in time-domain x(m,n) I can only show it by using direct z-transform)

Comment: If the question is about how to evaluate the inverse transform directly, you can compute the integral of $X z_1^{m - 1}$ wrt $z_1$ by finding the residue at $z_1 = \infty$ and then compute the integral of the result times $z_2^{n - 1}$ the same way. If the question is about how to go from one inverse transform to the other, you have
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} f(n) z^{-2 n} =
\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} g(n) z^{-n},$$
so $g(n) = f(n/2) [n \in 2 \mathbb N]$.